# Maintaining label encoding across different files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I know how to use scikit-learn and pandas to encode my categorical data. I've been using the category codes in pandas for now which I later will transform into an OneHot encoded format for ML.

My issues is that I need to create a pre-processing pipeline for multiple files with the same data format. I've discovered that using the pandas category codes encoding is not consistent, even if the categories (strings) in the data are identical across multiple files.

Is there a way to do this encoding lexicographically so that it's done the same way across all files or is there any specific method that can be used which would result in the same encoding when applied on multiple files?

Comment: Do you have an example with some data?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing I can share. But to give you a good idea.. I have the column 'race' in two files, each containing the value "White" in various rows. Using pandas.cat.codes, it is possible to get the number 1 for White in one file and 2 in the other.

Answer (score 0):

The `LabelEncoder` like all other Sklearn-Transformers has three certain methods:

1. `fit()`: Creates the labels given some input data
2. `transform()`: Transforms data to the labels of the encoder instance. It must have called `fit()` before or will throw an error
3. `fit_transform()`: That's a convenience-method that will create the labels and transform the data directly.

I'm guessing you are calling `fit_transform` everywhere. To fix this, just call the `fit`-method once (on a superset of all your data because it will throw an error if it encounters a label that was not present in the data you called `fit` on) and than use the `transform` method.

Comment: I was a bit unclear on the question. This is a good answer, but my issue is that I won't be able to 'fit' data, then apply transformations across multiple files. All files will always be "seen for the first time" although with the same format and values/categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scikit Learn's [One Hot Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) module. First create an object and call `.fit()` then you can use `.transform()` on multiple files.

```py
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(X1)
X1 = enc.tranform(X1)
X2 = enc.tranform(X2)
X3 = enc.tranform(X3)
```